# How to access dropdownlist in static method

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following static method.

```
public static List<string> GetAutoCompleteData(string StudentId)
    {
            List<string> result = new List<string>();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=SMS"))
            {
                //using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select  StudentId,StudentName from tblStudent where StudentId LIKE '%'+@SearchText+'%'", con))
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select  T1.StudentName,T1.StudentId from tblStudent T1 where StudentId LIKE '%'+@SearchText+'%' except  select T2.StudentName, T2.StudentId from tblStudentAcademics T2 where T2.AcademicYear='" +Dropdownvalue + "'", con))
                {

                    con.Open();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", StudentId);
                    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        result.Add(dr["StudentId"].ToString() + "-" + dr["StudentName"].ToString());
                    }
                    return result;
                }

        }
    }
```

I need to write ddlAcadeic.selectedvalue.tostring() in place of Dropdownvalue.Help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dropdownlist object is non static member of your class (Web Page) and **static methods can not access not static members**. Pass the dropdownList value to static method when you call it.

**[Static Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx)**

> Static methods and properties cannot access non-static fields and
>   events in their containing type, and they cannot access an instance
>   variable of any object unless it is explicitly passed in a method
>   parameter.

*Static method definition*

```
public static List GetAutoCompleteData(string StudentId, string dropdownvalue ) {
  //Your code
}
```

*Static method call*

```
StaticMethodClass.GetAutoCompleteData("studendId", dropdown.SelectedValue);
```

Comment: Dropdownvalue should be ddlAcademic.selectedValue.tostring().Inside the static function ddlAcademics is not coming.

Comment: Because static method could not access class members, you do not need ToString as SelectedValue is string property

Comment: I do not have a static class.I am using this static function for an ajax call.I need to get the dropdown selected value on text changing event of a textbox.I need to write in a sqlcommand to complete a query(for example select * from table where academic='"+dropdownvalue+"'.What should be the dropdown value?

Comment: Check my updated answer, static members can not access non static members in they are in non-static class

Comment: So it is not possible to access a non static dropdownlist inside a static function?

Comment: By passing as parameter

Comment: If I am passing a parameter inside a static function how I am going to access the value?

Comment: public static List GetAutoCompleteData(string StudentId, DropDownList dropdown ) {
   string val = dropdown.SelectedValue;
  //Your code
}

Comment: No need to write the Id of dropdownlist like ddlAcademic.selectedvalue.My problem is the id of the dropdownlist is not coming inside the static function.

Comment: I got the answer.we can use the following.

 protected void ddlAcademic_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["Academic"] = ddlAcademic.SelectedValue.ToString().Trim();
        
    }

i have used this session in the static function as context.Session["Academic"].it worked.

Comment: You could have changed the method to take the SelectedValue instead of using sessions

Comment: I tried for the same but the value did not come.So i tried this.Any issues am I gonna face if I use session?

Comment: Using session here seems needles and using session intensively without need may degrade performance. As for as the passing value, you have to call that method GetAutoCompleteData from ddlAcademic_SelectedIndexChanged and pass the ddlAcademic.SelectedValue