# How to call dropdownlist into Static Method?

Tags: c#, asp.net

> I have a Static Method that is

```
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static List<string> GetWorkPackages(string prefixText)
    {
        DataTable dt = getWorkpackages(ddlWp.SelectedValue);
        List<string> wps = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            wps.Add(dt.Rows[i][1].ToString());
        }
        return wps;
    }
```

Here Error Occured at ddlWp.SelectedValue(The name 'ddlWp' doesn't exist in the current context )

ddlWp is my asp control dropdownlist

> How can I pass my dropdown in static method ?

Comment: That doesn't work. [You can't access controls of your page from a `WebMethod`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133194/access-asp-net-control-from-static-webmethod-js-ajax-call).

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as it is only being called once, you could pass the value itself

```
public static List<string> GetWorkPackages(string prefixText, string ddlVal)
{
    DataTable dt = getWorkpackages(ddlVal);
    List<string> wps = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        wps.Add(dt.Rows[i][1].ToString());
    }
    return wps;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return the list to ajax from where the web method is called and bind it from ajax itself. Control won't get in web method.

Answer (score 0):

As Adil answered **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24484786/2118383)**

Dropdownlist object is non static member of your class (Web Page) and **static methods can not access not static members**. Pass the dropdownList value to static method when you call it.

**[Static Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx)**

> Static methods and properties cannot access non-static fields and
>   events in their containing type, and they cannot access an instance
>   variable of any object unless it is explicitly passed in a method
>   parameter.